# "Tinder Data Model": how to select candidates?

Tags: data-modeling

I have been thinking about of how Tinder might have setup their data model - especially the part to select the candidates to be shown (I'm not talking about the algorithm that determines the order, but only how to get all possible candidates in the first place). This process should only display other profile, that the current user did not already vote on.
So I could imagine this:
A table for the Users (>40mio entries), and another one for the swipes (>1,5 billion new entries each day). 
When selecting the candidates, one could join the two tables (+ obviously apply certain other selection criteria like the location, age range etc) and only return the users that the current user has not yet swiped for.

But: does that scale? Both of those tables are rather huge - so I guess at some point you would run into problem, right?

Furthermore, I read that Tinder is using AWS DynamoDB - so not a relational model. And this makes it even harder I guess...

So my question is: do you have an idea on how Tinder accomplished this?

Comment: Nice question, following post.